# Can't get boiler to stop heating! It's 80 degrees in the house

Tags: boiler, radiant-heating

I have two boiler systems. One for the heating of the house, and one for sink/shower hot water.

The boiler for the house will not turn off! It does kick on and off for a duration of time like it should, but the problem is that it shouldn't be kicking on at all anymore.

Thermostat is set at 60, turned off, and even the safety switch on the boiler unit is set to off. But it is STILL kicking on every 20 minutes or so.

It's 77 degrees outside... And 80 inside. I'm not only staying very hot even with air conditioner units going, and my pets aren't comfortable either, but I'm wasting money at this point.

How can I get it to stop! Asap?:

Comment: Is this a gas-fired boiler? If so, check or replace the thermal couple if the thermostat is not the problem.

Comment: Yes it is gas fired, is there any way to shut the system off until I can get one? I'm not sure why even the safety off switch on the unit doesn't even stop it. I would cut the breaker for it but there's more on that breaker.

Comment: Should have it on its own breaker then.

Comment: There should be a shutoff valve on the gas supply line, turn it off until repair is done.

Comment: @Solar Mike There is a switch on the old gas boiler that controls the booster pump only.

Comment: @Malsi What else is on the boiler's breaker? Can you relocate the "important" devices to a different circuit until this issue gets resolved?

Comment: For the system to kick in every 20 minutes or so I would be looking for welded contacts on the controller or thermostat. We will need photos, of the thermostat it could be the issue , fresh batteries if used? 
For now turn the gas valve to the house heat boiler off if there is no gas it can’t cycle. There should at minimum be a valve to turn it off at the gas valve if not a separate valve before. And photo of all the major components like controller boards, thermostats. That it is cycling makes me think it is more of a controller issue but there may be 2 issues creating problem, battery’s?

Comment: If the "safety switch" is off and the boiler still fires, the "safety switch" is not wired properly and should be corrected. Meanwhile the gas valve or circuit breaker would be reasonable.

Comment: There should be a local disconnect, if so, just turn the damn thing off.   If not figure out which breakers or fuses supply that beast and turn them off.  If they feed other important circuits, start disconnecting wires to the boiler, cap them and turn the breakers back on.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a hydronic heating system using [wax zone valves](https://www.savedollarstores.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/6517c62f5899ad6aa0ba23ceb3eeff97/2/1/212680_k_lg.jpg), which act both as water valves and as thermostat, these sometimes fail in the "on" position. If that is the case, disconnect one of the wires from the switch.

That said, as @Ecnerwal states, there is a serious issue with wiring if the boiler still fires with the safety switch "off". Is there perhaps another shut-off switch??

Comment: The OP has stated it is a gas-fired boiler. See comments directly under the question block.

Comment: @r13 -- gas boilers still have control circuits....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel As a gas boiler owner for 20 years, I've never learned I have got a control circuit or breaker. The only thing other than the booster pump that can require electricity maybe is the electronic module that was wired to the thermostat and thermal couple. I don't recall there was another wiring or switch though..

Comment: @r13 -- it'd be very odd to find an automatically-controlled gas boiler without one, whether it's powered by a HVAC transformer, directly from mains, or by a thermopile

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel If it does have electrical parts, then the unit is supper for serving 20 years without any trouble. I don't have HVAC, and as I said, there is no wiring, what is the thermopile?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The furnace/boiler I had was for the water heater system. That would be different for the forced-air system though.

Comment: @r13 -- the thermopile is the thing you're calling a "thermocouple" -- it's what generates the tiny voltage (a few hundred mV) needed to run the gas valve used with it (fireplaces also use this system)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thanks. Yes, I had that, one on the hot water boiler, and one on the heating boiler. One time I had a problem with the pilot, which was quickly resolved after replacing the thermal couple. I replaced it routinely at service, but not realizing that one came with the defect.